# Jenkins + pom.xml почему ошибку выдает?

Tags: jenkins

```
[ERROR] Malformed POM /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/sdc/pom.xml: expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">\n    <m... @6:7)  @
```

/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/sdc/pom.xml, line 6, column 7

```
    <groupId>airlanesairlanesisrael</groupId>
    <artifactId>airlanesairlanesisrael</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: бред! <project нужно вначале без закрытой скобки писать((( ужас сколько время потрачено. зачем такие сложности

Answer (score 1):

бред! `<project` нужно вначале без закрытой скобки писать((( ужас сколько время потрачено. зачем такие сложности